# Responsive SVG textpath для передвижения текста

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я пытаюсь обернуть блок новостей (который будет варьироваться по ширине и высоте) с анимированным SVG-текстом вокруг него. У меня получилось вот это:

```css
 #canvas{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 }
 .svg-container { 
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 100%; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="svg-container">
    <svg id="canvas" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 500 500">  
        <path width="100%"  id="curve" fill="none" d="M0,0 h200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z" />
        <text font-family="Helvetica" font-size="20" fill="black">
            <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="0%" id="text">Last News</textPath>
        <animate xlink:href="#text" attributeName="startOffset" from="0%" to="100%" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </text>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Это будет дочерний контент:

```
<div class="lastnews">
    <div class="post-grid">

        <a class="post-link" href="#">
        <div class="post">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768x461.png">
            <h2>Some very long long title with too many words</h2>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a class="post-link" href="#">
        <div class="post">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768x461.png">
            <h2>Some very long long title with too many words</h2>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a class="post-link" href="#">
        <div class="post">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768x461.png">
            <h2>Short title</h2>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a class="post-link" href="#">
        <div class="post">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768x461.png">
            <h2>Some very long long title with too many words</h2>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a class="post-link" href="#">
        <div class="post">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768x461.png">
            <h2>Some very long long title with too many words</h2>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a class="post-link" href="#">
        <div class="post">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768x461.png">
            <h2>Some very long long title with too many words</h2>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a class="post-link" href="#">
        <div class="post">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768x461.png">
            <h2>Some very long long title with too many words</h2>
        </div>
        </a>

        <a class="post-link" href="#">
        <div class="post">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768x461.png">
            <h2>Some very long long title with too many words</h2>
        </div>
        </a>            

    </div>
</div>
```

Я нашел несколько способов сделать svg responsive, но возможно ли сделать svg путь адаптируемым к дочернему контенту div?

вот результат, который я хотел бы получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Responsive SVG textpath wrapping dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60722088/7394871) от участника  [@Juárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1792659/ju%c3%a1rez).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60722088/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Вот как  это сделал бы я:  помещаю div с текстом и svg в один родительский блок `#wrap` с `position:relative`. А блок `.Text-container` имеет `position: absolute` и располагается над элементом svg.

Также `.text-container` имеет ширину 100%, но `height: auto`, поскольку содержимое является динамическим.

Вам понадобится размер `.text-container`, и вы будете использовать его для вычисления нового `viewBox` элемента svg и нового значения атрибута `d` `#curve` - траектории движения.

```js
let txtCont = document.querySelector(".text-container");
// получить размер текстового контейнера
let box = txtCont.getBoundingClientRect()

//установить новый viewBox элемента svg
canvas.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox",`-50 -30 310 ${box.height}`)
//установить новый атрибут d кривой
curve.setAttributeNS(null,"d", `M0,0 h200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v${box.height  - 100} a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-${box.height - 100} a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z`)
```

```css
#wrap {
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.text-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <svg id="canvas"  viewBox="-50 -30 310 310">  
        <path width="100%"  id="curve" fill="none" stroke="gold" d="" />
        <text font-family="Helvetica" font-size="20" fill="black">
            <textPath xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="0%" id="text">Last News</textPath>
        <animate xlink:href="#text" attributeName="startOffset" from="0%" to="100%" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </text>
    </svg>

<div class="text-container">
  <p>I'm trying to wrap a block of news (which will vary on width & height) with an animated SVG textpath around it. I got this so far</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пожалуйста, измените текст `.text-контейнера`, чтобы увидеть изменение анимации.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Responsive SVG textpath wrapping dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60723994/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>